# doctrine SINGLE_TABLE InheritanceType get all rows

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have entity

```
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 */
class Contact extends BaseUser
```

and

```
class MyContact extends Contact
{
```

and have name MyBundle:MyContact name and want get all Contact rows not only MyContact how to do this ?

can i get base inheritance class for MyBundle:MyContact ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the repository for the base entity:

```
// assuming $entityManager is available
$contactList = $entityManager
    ->getRepository('MyBundle:Contact')
    ->findAll();
```

Comment: ok but i add MyContact because it have extra connections with cascade delete, but ok i change discriminator filed in all Contact to MyContact so now all is MyContact so i can delete it